# When back button of action bar is pressed oncreate is called

Tags: android, android-activity

I have to activities, one **MainActivity** and another activity : **Tech**. Activity Tech is launched from the **MainActivity**. Then when I press the back button of the action bar in the activity **Tech**. **MainActivity** is again created.

This doesn't happen when physical back button is pressed.

I specified the parent Activity on my Manifest file as :

```
<activity
        android:name="com.helloworld.welcome.Tech"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_tech"
        android:parentActivityName="com.helloworld.welcome.MainActivity" >

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.helloworld.welcome.MainActivity"/>
    </activity>
```

Answer (score 7):

try to add the following to your parent activity in the manifest file

```
android:launchMode="singleTop"
```

Comment: If the parent activity has launch mode <standard>, and the up intent does not contain FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP, the parent activity is popped off the stack, and a new instance of that activity is created on top of the stack to receive the intent

Comment: +Mourice, it isn't workin. The same thing is happening.

Comment: try to add 
the following to your parent activity in the manifest file

android:launchMode="singleTop"

Comment: When I made this it's working now :

switch (item.getItemId()) {
     // Respond to the action bar's Up/Home button
     case android.R.id.home:
         finish();
         return true;
     }

Comment: @Hello World this worked for me, thanks. For those who come after: place the code in onOptionsItemSelected() of the activity in which the 'up' button is being pressed.

Answer (score 3):

On pressing the back button, a new instance of that activity (the one which we are returning to) is created.

Adding the `android:launchMode="singleTop"` to manifest file makes sure that no new instance of that activity is created if there already exists one.

Reference:
https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/tasks-and-back-stack